# Changing Avatar trouble

Tags: support, user-profiles, gravatar

When I try to change my avatar by clicking "Change Picture" under my profile, I am taken to www.gravatar.com.  But I have an myOpenId account with an option to change my profile picture.  Which one actually changes my avatar?
**Side Note:** When I tried changing my avatar in my myOpenId preferences, nothing changes on my Stack Exchange accounts.  When I tried gravatar.com, nothing happens *except* when I click "accounts" tab under my profile, under the "related accounts" all the avatars have changed to the one I wanted but have not changed on the actually sites.

**Side Note 2:** No matter what I try, my avatar is stuck on that e-mail hash code image creator.  Could it be a conflict between myOpenId and Gravatar.com?

Answer (score 4):

Pictures from Gravatar are used. It might take some time for changes to take effect. Currently, you're displaying the Super Mario ghost.

[image: Boo! I'm a ghost!]

You might even want to clear your browser's cache.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know which one has preference. Yea that's my image. For awhile it wasn't showing it, but now the issue is that under my profile, the hash code image is still showing.

Comment: @ADonahue With me, only the the ghost is showing for you everywhere!